# Cannot get a bootstrap dropdown to display properly on startup

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can demonstrate my issue in my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4T2TT/

```
            <div class="btn-group open">
                <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" id="reject-button" data-toggle="dropdown">Reject<span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a id="image-illegible" href="/Home/Reject/44001FFF-E07A-4881-A16E-9C4FF7DFACB8/Message">Image is illegible</a></li>
                    <li><a id="invalid-bill" href="#">Image is not a valid bill</a></li>
                    <li><a id="images-incomplete" href="#">Bill images are incomplete</a></li>
                    <li><a id="missing-information" href="#">Cannot find find required information</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

On start up the dropdown is displaying but I do not understand how to make it start hidden rather than shown.

Is there a setting to make it start up hidden or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the class '**open**' from `<div class="btn-group ">`

http://jsfiddle.net/4T2TT/1/

Comment: +1 Thanks for that, works a treat, I will award you the answer in 8 mins when it lets me. Thanks again.